# Overwrite original file by other with modifications

Tags: c, windows, file

I have an original file students.txt. I want to overwrite with the file studentsmodified.txt .I tried using rename but it seems that rename cant overwrite file:

```
rename("studentsmodified.txt","students.txt");
```

how can i do it?

Comment: Check `errno` to see why it failed - could be a permissions problem, or file open.

Comment: File exists says the error

Comment: It should work on any well-behaved OS, e.g. Linux. Are you perhaps trying to do this on a non-POSIX OS, e.g. [Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw5t957f.aspx) ?

Comment: Yes, windows.....How can i do it on windows?

Comment: OK - I've tagged your question as `windows` now - you should probably do this for any future questions, since Windows has many incompatibilities with standard operating systems. See the [MSDN entry for rename()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw5t957f.aspx), particularly the part that says *"The new name must not be the name of an existing file or directory"*. You'll probably have to delete or rename the file that you want to replace before the call to `rename()`.

Comment: So...there is no way of overwriting files in windows?

Comment: I don't know - I don't use Windows if I can possibly avoid it. Maybe you can do a little reading of the MSDN documentation, or just use workaround I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Portable version using [`remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/remove) and [`rename`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rename):

`#include <stdio.h>`

...

```
remove("students.txt");
rename("studentsmodified.txt","students.txt");
```

Windows-Specific version using the [`MoveFileEx` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240(v=vs.85).aspx):

`#include <Windows.h>`

...

```
MoveFileEx("studentsmodified.txt","students.txt",MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING);
```